# pyspark filter get java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot evaluate expression after using pandas udf

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The code:

```
    spark = SparkBase().spark

    data = [(1, 102193, 10, "2021-01-22", "2021-01-22 10:44:31"),
            (1, 103525, 20, "2021-01-22", "2021-01-22 10:44:32"),
            (3, 103685, 30, "2021-01-22", "2021-01-22 10:44:31"),
            (2, 102193, 40, "2021-01-22", "2021-01-22 10:43:41"),
            (2, 103525, 50, "2021-01-22", "2021-01-22 10:43:42"),
            (2, 103685, 60, "2021-01-22", "2021-01-22 10:43:43"),
            ]
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "uid", "profit", "start_date", "start_time"])

    @F.pandas_udf("int", F.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_AGG)
    def profit_in_30_hand(profit, start_time):
        d = pd.concat([profit, start_time], axis=1)
        d = d.rename(columns={"_0": "profit", "_1": "start_time"})
        d = d.sort_values("start_time", ascending=False)
        profits = d.profit.iloc[:3].sum()
        return int(profits)

    df = df.groupby(["id", "start_date"]).agg(profit_in_30_hand(df.profit, df.start_time).alias("profits"))
    df.show()

    df.where("profits > 30").show() # this get wrong
```

After using pandas udf, `df.where("profits > 30").show()` get exceptions:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o146.showString.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
Exchange hashpartitioning(id#6L, start_date#9, 200)
+- *(1) Project [id#6L, profit#8L, start_date#9, start_time#10]
   +- *(1) Filter (profit_in_30_hand(profit#8L, start_time#10) > 30)
      +- Scan ExistingRDD[id#6L,uid#7L,profit#8L,start_date#9,start_time#10]

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.doExecute(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.inputRDDs(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:379)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SortExec.inputRDDs(SortExec.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:615)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.AggregateInPandasExec.doExecute(AggregateInPandasExec.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:339)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3383)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2544)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2544)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3364)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3363)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2544)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2758)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot evaluate expression: profit_in_30_hand(input[2, bigint, true], input[4, string, true])
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Unevaluable$class.doGenCode(Expression.scala:261)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.PythonUDF.doGenCode(PythonUDF.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression$$anonfun$genCode$2.apply(Expression.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression$$anonfun$genCode$2.apply(Expression.scala:105)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression.genCode(Expression.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BinaryExpression.nullSafeCodeGen(Expression.scala:525)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BinaryExpression.defineCodeGen(Expression.scala:508)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BinaryComparison.doGenCode(predicates.scala:566)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression$$anonfun$genCode$2.apply(Expression.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression$$anonfun$genCode$2.apply(Expression.scala:105)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression.genCode(Expression.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$FilterExec$$genPredicate$1(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec$$anonfun$13.apply(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec$$anonfun$13.apply(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:163)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:296)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.doConsume(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.consume(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.doProduce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:391)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.InputAdapter.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.doProduce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.produce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.doProduce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$$anonfun$produce$1.apply(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CodegenSupport$class.produce(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ProjectExec.produce(basicPhysicalOperators.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doCodeGen(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:532)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:586)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec.prepareShuffleDependency(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.ShuffleExchangeExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(ShuffleExchangeExec.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:52)
    ... 49 more
```

spark version: 2.4.0

requirements:

```
pandas==1.3.5
pyarrow==0.13.0
pyspark==2.4.0
```

Comment: There seems to be no issue in spar 3.0+. Try modifying to `df.where(col('profits') > 30).show()`

Comment: Same error occurred in spark2.4.0. @wwnde